# How could i get O(m+n) using greedy?

Tags: analysis, greedy

How could I design an algorithm greedy `O(m+n)` for this case

Given two arrangements `L1` and `L2`, where `| L1 | = n` and `| L2 | = m`.

`L2` is said to be a subsequence of `L1` if elements can be removed from `L1` to get `L2`. This means that there are `m` indexes `ik∈ [0..n]` such that `L1 [ik] = L2 [j]` for each `j∈ [0..m]`. Design a greedy algorithm in `O (n + m)` that detects if `L2` is a subsequence of `L1` and outputs the `ik` indices in `L1` in the case that `L2` is a subsequence of `L1`.

Examples:

```
Input L1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] L2 = [3 5 7 9] Output ik = [2 4 6 8]

Input L1 = [2 1 4 3 6 5 7 8 9 10] L2 = [1 6 5 10] Output ik = [1 4 5 9]

Input L1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] L2 = [1 5 9 12] Output L2 is not subsequence of L1
```

I have been doing the classic code for this using this

```
bool isSubsequence(string str1, string str2) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

while (j<str1.length() && i<str2.length()){
    if(str1[j]==str2[i]){
        cout<<i<<" ";
        j++;
    }

    i++;
} 
    
return j==str1.length(); 
}
```

But i dont know how to get `O(m+n)` using greedy.
Thanks

Comment: That approach already is greedy -- it simply takes elements from str1 (L2) that match elements of str2 (L1) as soon as it can -- and assuming that `length()` is a constant time operation, it already does run in O(m+n).

Comment: i was thinking it is O(max(m,n))

Comment: Yes O( max (m, n) ) = O(m + n). The addition appears to me the more common way to express that though.